# What is the grammatical explanation for an 'It looks like ...' clause? (dummy subjects)

Tags: grammar, subjects, dummy-it

Recently, I have been trying to understand the nuances of language to turn myself into a better writer. This has led me to the 'dummy subject' or 'dummy pronoun.' I am clear on the function of 'there,' but 'it' has proven to be more confusing.

I am aware of this subject being used to talk about time, weather, and distance. I am also aware of its use in expletives (changing the position of the subject). However, I can't seem to grasp this sentence construction: 'It looks like ....'
An example of what I mean is 'It looks like we've won' or 'It looks like they've gone home.'

To me, the use of 'It' at the beginning of the sentence seems to be a dummy pronoun, as I can't figure out what else it could refer to.
Does anyone know the exact grammatical explanation for this?

Comment: 'The appearance of the situation is that we have won.'

Comment: This is one of the usages of what's best given the overarching classification _non-referential 'it'_. (This is not to say that more detailed analyses aren't available, nor that they're not valuable.) The word is pressed into use to fulfil the desperate need English sees for a subject, even when an obvious SV, SVO, SVC structure isn't available. _What is it_ that is doing the looking [like] / appearing [that]? Where is the agent? Note that conversationally, the improbable _it_ may often be dropped: "Looks like we've won!" (But not "Appears we've won!" as _appear_ is in a more formal register.

Comment: Grammatically, it’s like any other sentence. It moves…, it struggles… it shines…., it looks...(.) In the sentence "It looks like we have won." Both the sentences, "It looks.... (?)" and "We have won." can be parsed meaningfully.  It looks; does it look? Yes, it does...(.) We have won. Have we won? Yes we have...(.)  Possibly, in a construction like this, 'like' functions as an intransitive verb of incomplete predication.

Comment: [It's just another empty *it*.](https://editorsmanual.com/articles/grammatical-subject-in-its-raining/#empty-it-with-look-seem-appear-etc) *It's raining.* What's raining?? *It looks like we won.* What looks like we won??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule is called [*Extraposition*](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20extraposition).
It applies to a sentential subject -- an infinitive clause or a *that*-clause, for instance:

- ***For him to leave early** would be a good idea*. (infinitive clause subject)
- ***That he left early** was surprising.* (*that*-clause subject)

Extraposition moves those heavy subjects to the end of the sentence, where they are easier to process, and leaves behind a dummy *it* to (pretend to) be the subject noun phrase. That produces the kind of sentence English likes - starting with a simple subject (preferably a pronoun), followed by a simple verb (preferably an auxiliary verb), with all the complicated stuff piled up at the end.

- ***It**  would be a good idea **for him to leave early***. (Extraposed infinitive)
- ***It** was surprising **that he left early**.* (Extraposed *that*-clause)

Whether Extraposition can apply or not is governed by the predicate of the main clause;
*be a good idea* and *be surprising* are both predicates that allow it.

Often, as with verbs like *seems* or *looks like*, Extraposition is obligatory; the ungrammatical

- **That he left early seems*
- **That he left early looks like*

Extrapose to

- *It seems (that) he left early.* (*that* is optional)
- *It looks like (*that) he left early.* (*that* is not allowed)

Comment: I don't see "looks like" as a verb, nor do I see the relevance of extraposition. In "It looked like [he left early]" the bracketed element is a non-expandable content clause as complement of the **preposition** "like". The whole PP "like he left early" is then complement of the verb "looked".